# When must I use super() to call superclass methods?

Tags: python

I understand why I call super() for the ElectricCar class, to be able to call methods defined by the parent Car class. But why do I not have to call super() in order to be able to call Battery class methods such as my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()?

I am working through Python Crash Course where this example is from.

```
from default_attributes import Car


class Battery:
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car"""

    def __init__(self, battery_size=75):
        """Initialize the batter's attributes"""
        self.battery_size = battery_size

    def describe_battery(self):
        """Print a statement describing the battery size."""
        print(f"This car has a {self.battery_size}-KWh battery.")

    def get_range(self):
        """Print a statement about the range this battery provides"""
        if self.battery_size == 75:
            range = 260
        elif self.battery_size == 100:
            range = 315

        print(f"This car can go about {range} miles on a full charge.")


class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles"""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """
        Initialize attributes of the parent class.
        Then initialize attributes specific to an electric car.
        """
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()

    def fill_gas_tank(self):
        # Overide parent methods by defining one with the same name.
        """Electric cars don't have gas tanks"""
        print("This car doesn't need a gas tank!")


my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2019)
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
```

Comment: `Battery` has no superclass.

Comment: @szatkus I must be thinking about it wrong then. Would I figured Battery would be considered the superclass of my_tesla.battery

Comment: The only superclass in this code is `Car`, because `ElectricCar` inherits from it.

Comment: An `ElecticCar` *is* a `Car`, but *has* a `Battery`. Every class as what is called a method resolution order (MRO), which is a linear sequence of the classes found in its inheritance hierarchy. `super` provides a way to call a method of the "next" class in the MRO, depending on which method is currently being executed.

Comment: `Battery` is simply the *class* of the value `my_tesla.battery`.

Comment: @szatkus Oh! So since my_tesla.battery is a completely new instance of, and does not inherit from, Battery, it has no superclass. I should have seen that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is confounding inheritance with composition. Here is a good [article](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3409071/java-challenger-7-debugging-java-inheritance.html#:%7E:text=Inheritance%20and%20composition%20are%20two,the%20sum%20of%20its%20parts.) on the difference between the two. Whenever you inherit a class, you need to call super. Whenever you compose a class (electric car) with another class (battery) you do not. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

You only need to call `super` to access a method that your subclass overrides (*i.e.*, has a method of the same name). Methods that the superclass defines and the subclass doesn't override can be called as methods of the instance (or of the class if you provide an explicit instance as the first argument), because they are inherited, but defining the method locally means that the local method is found before the definition in the superclass.

The following program might explain the confusion:

```
class SuperClass():
    def non_overridden(self):
        print("SuperClass non_overridden")
    def overridden(self):
        print("SuperClass overriden")

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def overridden(self):
        print("SubClass overriden")
    def do_it_all(self):
        super().overridden()
        self.overridden()
        self.non_overridden()

sc = SubClass()
sc.do_it_all()
```

A formal [explanation of Python's method resolution process](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) by Python's inventor is worth reading, and is still pretty much valid today.

Comment: Thanks so much. The book doesn't touch on this, so this helps a ton.

Comment: Not sure what book you are following, but this is pretty standard object-oriented stuff. Glad it helped!